# Failed to open Model driven PowerApps

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-modeldriven

When I publish the model-driven app, it leads to this page. I click to see my app, it doesn't work, but it returns to this page again. I don't know what the issue here. I watched some tutorials and see that left corner is "Dynamics 365" but mine is "PowerApps". I'm not sure this causes the issue?

[image]

Comment: did you tried https://home.dynamics.com there you can find your app?

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Should be a temporary glitch. Navigate to `https://<orgname>.crm.dynamics.com/apps` url & click the app thumbnail again to see. Or refresh the browser, even `https://home.dynamics.com` should work like AnkUser said.

Regarding the left top branding logo, probably the new trial orgs getting the **PowerApps** logo rather than **Dynamics 365**. You can change it to your company logo under `Settings - Customizations - Themes`. That should not be a problem. You can click that PowerApps Logo to see the top Jewel menu reloads fully.